# Drools Hibernate JPA Annotation Many to Many Example DRL

Tags: java, hibernate, drools

I'm new on Hibernate and Drools, I want that drools evaluate a rule for a given Person and fire only if person ID exist on a given table.

For example:  If I have a

> *Table Called 'Person' with fields: personID='1015'. 
>   A table called 'likes' with fields: id=1, name=sports.*
>
> And a Intermediate *Table Called 'personLikes' with fields: personID=1015, idLikes=1.*

And I load three diferent Persons with: `personID=1015`, `personID=1020`, `personID=1035`.

On that case rule execute only for person `code=1015`.

**Question** is: How can I construct that rule?

Here are my code.

DRL FILE:

```
        rule healthy when    
            p: Person()
            i: Interes(nombre=="Sports")
            InteresPersonaId(persona==p,interes==i)
            //InteresesPersona(pk==ip)      

        then
            System.out.println("OK" + p.id + "LIKES" +i.nombre);


    end
```

DB:

```
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screb`.`person` (
              `idPerson` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
              `gender` CHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              `age` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              `estrato` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              `idLocalizacion` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`idPerson`),
              INDEX `FK_location_idx` (`idLocalizacion` ASC),
              CONSTRAINT `FK_location`
                FOREIGN KEY (`idLocalizacion`)
                REFERENCES `screb`.`localizacion` (`idLocalizacion`)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
            ENGINE = InnoDB
            DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

            USE `screb` ;

            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            -- Table `screb`.`interes`
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screb`.`interes` (
              `idInteres` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              `descripcion` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`idInteres`))
            ENGINE = InnoDB
            DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            -- Table `screb`.`interesesxpersona`
            -- -----------------------------------------------------
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `screb`.`interesesxpersona` (
              `persona` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
              `Interes` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
              PRIMARY KEY (`persona`, `Interes`),
              INDEX `FK_PERS_INT_idx` (`Interes` ASC),
              CONSTRAINT `FK_IN_PER`
                FOREIGN KEY (`persona`)
                REFERENCES `screb`.`person` (`idPerson`)
                ON DELETE NO ACTION
                ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
              CONSTRAINT `FK_PERS_INT`
                FOREIGN KEY (`Interes`)
                REFERENCES `screb`.`interes` (`idInteres`)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
                ON UPDATE CASCADE)
            ENGINE = InnoDB
            DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Class to load facts:

```
public class Campaign {

            public static final void main(String[] args) {
                KieContainer kc =     KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer();
                KieSession ksession = kc.newKieSession("CampaignKS");

                PersonManager person = new PersonManager();
                List<Person> list = person.listEvents();
                for(Person p :list){
                    ksession.insert(p);
                }



                InteresManager interes = new InteresManager();
                List<Interes> listaIntereses = interes.listIntereses();
                for(Interes i :listaIntereses){
                    ksession.insert(i);
                }



                ksession.fireAllRules();

                ksession.dispose();

            }

        }
```

Mapping Classes:

```
      @Entity
                @Table(name="interes",schema="screb")
                public class Interes implements java.io.Serializable {

                public int idInteres;
                public String nombre;
                public String descripcion;
                public Set<InteresesPersona> interesesP = new HashSet<InteresesPersona>(0);


                public Interes(){}
                public Interes(int interes,String nombre, String descripcion){
                    this.idInteres=interes;
                    this.nombre=nombre;
                    this.descripcion=descripcion;
                }
                public Interes(int interes,String nombre, String descripcion, Set<InteresesPersona>interesesPersona){
                    this.idInteres=interes;
                    this.nombre=nombre;
                    this.descripcion=descripcion;
                    this.interesesP=interesesPersona;
                }

                @Id @GeneratedValue
                @Column(name="idInteres")
                public int getIdInteres() {
                    return idInteres;
                }
                public void setIdInteres(int idInteres) {
                    this.idInteres = idInteres;
                }
                @Column(name="nombre")
                public String getNombre() {
                    return nombre;
                }
                public void setNombre(String nombre) {
                    this.nombre = nombre;
                }
                @Column(name="descripcion")
                public String getDescripcion() {
                    return descripcion;
                }
                public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
                    this.descripcion = descripcion;
                }

                @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.interes")
                public Set<InteresesPersona> getInteresesP(){
                    return this.interesesP;

                }
                public void setInteresesP(Set<InteresesPersona> interesesPersona){
                    this.interesesP=interesesPersona;

                }   
            }
```

Class InteresesPersona (PersonLikes):

```
            @Entity
            @Table(name="interes_persona",schema = "screb")
            @AssociationOverrides({
                    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.persona", 
                        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idPerson")),
                    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.interes", 
                        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idInteres")) })

            public class InteresesPersona implements java.io.Serializable{


                public InteresPersonaId pk = new InteresPersonaId();
                private Date createdDate;

                public InteresesPersona(){}

                @EmbeddedId
                public InteresPersonaId getPk() {
                    return pk;
                }

                public void setPk(InteresPersonaId pk) {
                    this.pk = pk;
                }

                @Transient
                public Person getPersona() {
                    return getPk().getPersona();
                }

                public void setPersona(Person persona) {
                    getPk().setPersona(persona);
                }

                @Transient
                public Interes getInteres() {
                    return getPk().getInteres();
                }

                public void setInteres(Interes interes) {
                    getPk().setInteres(interes);
                }

                @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
                @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false, length = 10)
                public Date getCreatedDate() {
                    return this.createdDate;
                }

                public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
                    this.createdDate = createdDate;
                }


                public boolean equals(Object o) {
                    if (this == o)
                        return true;
                    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                        return false;

                    InteresesPersona that = (InteresesPersona) o;

                    if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk())
                            : that.getPk() != null)
                        return false;

                    return true;
                }

                public int hashCode() {
                    return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
                }


            }
```

Class InteresesPersonaID (PersonLikesID)

```
            @Embeddable

            public class InteresPersonaId implements java.io.Serializable {

                public Person persona;
                public Interes interes;

                @ManyToOne
                public Person getPersona() {
                    return persona;
                }

                public void setPersona(Person persona) {
                    this.persona = persona;
                }

                @ManyToOne
                public Interes getInteres() {
                    return interes;
                }

                public void setInteres(Interes interes) {
                    this.interes = interes;
                }

                public boolean equals(Object o) {
                    if (this == o) return true;
                    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

                    InteresPersonaId that = (InteresPersonaId) o;

                    if (persona != null ? !persona.equals(that.persona) : that.persona!= null) return false;
                    if (interes != null ? !interes.equals(that.interes) : that.interes != null)
                        return false;

                    return true;
                }

                public int hashCode() {
                    int result;
                    result = (persona != null ? persona.hashCode() : 0);
                    result = 31 * result + (interes != null ? interes.hashCode() : 0);
                    return result;
                }


            }
```

Class Person

```
            @Entity
            @Table(name="person",schema="screb")

            public class Person implements java.io.Serializable{

                public String id;
                public char gender;
                public int age;
                public int estrato;
                public Set<InteresesPersona> interesesP = new HashSet<InteresesPersona>(0);


                public Person(){}
                public Person(String id,char genero,int edad,int estrato){
                    this.id=id;
                    this.gender=genero;
                    this.age=edad;
                    this.estrato=estrato;
                }
                public Person(String id,char genero,int edad,int estrato,Set<InteresesPersona>interesesPersona){
                    this.id=id;
                    this.gender=genero;
                    this.age=edad;
                    this.estrato=estrato;
                    this.interesesP = interesesPersona;
                }

                @Id 
                @Column(name="idPerson")
                public String getId() {
                    return id;
                }


                public void setId(String id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }

                @Column(name="gender")
                public char getGender() {
                    return gender;
                }


                public void setGender(char gender) {
                    this.gender = gender;
                }

                @Column(name="age")
                public int getAge() {
                    return age;
                }


                public void setAge(int age) {
                    this.age = age;
                }

                @Column(name="estrato")
                public int getEstrato() {
                    return estrato;
                }


                public void setEstrato(int estrato) {
                    this.estrato = estrato;
                }    

                @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy= "pk.persona",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
                public Set<InteresesPersona> getInteresesP(){
                    return this.interesesP;

                }

                public void setInteresesP(Set<InteresesPersona> interesesPersona){
                    this.interesesP=interesesPersona;

                }

                @Override
                public boolean equals(Object o){
                    if(this==o){return true;}
                    if(o==null||getClass()!=o.getClass()){return false;}

                    Person person = (Person) o;

                    if (!id.equals(person.id)){return false;}
                    if (gender!=person.gender){return false;}
                    if (age!=person.age){return false;}
                    if (estrato!=person.estrato){return false;}

                    return true;

                }

                @Override
                public int hashCode(){
                    int result = id.hashCode();


                    return result;
                }

            }
```

Class PersonManager:

```
        public class PersonManager {
             public List listEvents(){
                Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                session.beginTransaction();
                Query query= session.createQuery("from Person");
                List<Person> list = query.list();       
                session.getTransaction().commit();



                return list;
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java classes are somewhat redundant. This doesn't matter for writing rules but it may affect DB access. - Is InteresesPersona different from InteresesPersonaId?

```
rule "a person's interests a"
when
    Person( $id: id, $pip: interesesP ) 
    $ip: InteresesPersona() from $pip
    Interes( interesesP contains $ip, $nom: nombre )
then
    System.out.println( $id + " likes " + $nom );
end
```

Fires for each combination of person and interest, grouped by persons. (Rearrange to have it grouped by interest.)

If you would insert InteresesPersonaId objects you could also write

```
rule  "a person's interests b"
when
    $ip: InteresesPersonaId( $p: persona, $i: interes)
    Person( this == $p, $id: id ) 
    Interes( this == $i, $nom: nombre )
then
    System.out.println( $id + " likes " + $nom );
end
```

But note that this rule may produce results in a random order, i.e., not grouped by person.

Comment: yes, there are different, `InteresPersonaId` contains keys for intermediate relationship `InteresesPersona`. It's Means contains mapped keys `idPerson` from table `Person` and key `idInteres` from table `Interes`. and `InteresPersona` represent to intermediate table relationship One-to-Many between `InteresPersona` and `Person`, and `InteresPersona` and `Interes`, and contains `InteresPersonaId`(KEY) and additional field called `createdDate`.

Comment: When I ran the rule it's throwing the error failed to lazily initialize a collection. so I change `FetchType.LAZY` to `FetchType.EAGER` and now runs. but rule doesn't fire I don't know If facts are loading correctly (class Campaign) or if i have to load facts from `InteresesPersona` too

Comment: With the first rule you shouldn't have to insert `InteresesPersona` as facts but they must be stored in the collection interesesP of `Person` when you insert a `Person` as a fact. With the second rule they must be inserted as facts.